# HeapSort doesn't sort array correctly

Tags: java, heapsort

I can't figure out why it is not working. It is for my class and I am not allowed to change the variables that are put into each method: I'd be very happy about any ideas!

```
public class HeapSort {
    private int[] nodes;
    
    public HeapSort(int[] nodes) {
        this.nodes=nodes;
    }
    
    public void buildHeap() {
    
        for(int i=nodes.length / 2 - 1; i>=0; i--) {
            heapify(nodes.length,i);
        }
        for(int i=nodes.length-1; i>0; i--) {
            int temp=nodes[0];
            nodes[0]=nodes[i];
            nodes[i]=temp;
            
            heapify(i,0);
        }
    }
    
    private void heapify(int curIdx, int endIdx) {
        int leftChildPos = endIdx * 2 + 1;
        int rightChildPos = endIdx * 2 + 2;
        int largestPos = endIdx;
        
        if(leftChildPos < nodes.length && nodes[leftChildPos] > nodes[largestPos]) {
            largestPos = leftChildPos;
        }
        if(rightChildPos < nodes.length && nodes[rightChildPos] > nodes[largestPos]) {
            largestPos = rightChildPos;
        }
        if(largestPos!=endIdx) {
            int swapTemp = nodes[endIdx];
            nodes[endIdx]=nodes[largestPos];
            nodes[largestPos]=swapTemp;
            
            heapify(curIdx, largestPos);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have example code you are using to run this, with expected output?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately we were only given a Test class that uses already compiled methodes. Therefore it's probably not helpful.